# How can I pick certain columns and append them under the other using Google Sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, union

How can I get Away Team and append them to the last row of Home Team (Being Home or Away doesn't matter, in this case), and get AST and append to HST. I 'd see Date being repeated so as to keep data consistent.

I've tried combining `query()` with `importrange()`, `filter()`, etc, but without any luck so far.

Here's the data:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
={flatten({A2:A,A2:A}),flatten({B2:B,B2:B}), flatten(C2:D),flatten(E2:F)}
```

or according to your local parameters

```
={flatten({A2:A\A2:A})\flatten({B2:B\B2:B})\ flatten(C2:D)\flatten(E2:F)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FLATTEN` combines data alternately. With range merging, lists can be merged one after the other.

```
={C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(TRUE,C:C="",0)-1);D2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TRUE,D:D="",0))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Basic! I ended up using Mike's solution as he responded first.